# SSIS creates Empty File

Tags: connection, outputstream, ssis-2012

I have a script control which splits my data down two file streams and into two File Destinations.  Unfortunately even if there are no records for one of the streams the destination file Is still created.  How can this be prevented.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is how the SSIS behaves i.e. creating destination files even if there is no data. You would need a workaround to get this through -

1. Insert a 'Row Count' transformation between Script Task and your 'Destination File' and assign a variable to it say @intNumberOfRows.
2. Connect the Data Flow Task to a 'File Task' to delete the empty file created by using a conditional expression based on the value of @intNumberOfRows set to 0.